# Python script for zlib decompression

Tags: python, parsing, compression

I'm looking for feedback/improvement on code that I wrote. It's a function that scans a file for zlib headers and returns the header, offset, and decompressed data. In main, below the function, I use that data to find the offset beginning after the final zlib compressed data which I need that offset. I'm looking to improve by making it more compact and efficient, specifically. Any advice/improvements would be greatly appreciated. Here's my code:

```
import zlib


def inflate(infile):
    data = infile.read()
    offset = 0
    while offset < len(data):
        window = data[offset : offset + 2]
        for key, value in zlib_headers.items():
            if window == key:
                decomp_obj = zlib.decompressobj()
                yield key, offset, decomp_obj.decompress(data[offset:])
        if offset == len(data):
            break
        offset += 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    zlib_headers = {b"\x78\x01": 3, b"\x78\x9c": 6, b"\x78\xda": 9}

    with open("input_file", "rb") as infile:
        *_, last = inflate(infile)

    key, offset, data = last
    start_offset = offset + len(zlib.compress(data, zlib_headers[key]))

    print(start_offset)
```

Answer (score 1):

It works, it's reasonably clear in that you use a library. Mostly it's fine.

Give `inflate` a docstring which clearly says what it takes in, what it returns. Rename it, because it doesn't inflate one thing that's passed in.

Switch the loop to be simply `for offset in range(len(data)):`

You may need to deal with errors thrown by the library when the zlib 2-byte header randomly appears inside a file.

`zlib_headers` is a global. Move it out of the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block and make it UPPERCASE. Remove the values (3, 6, 9) which are never used, make it a `set`. Or it would be reasonable to make it a regex.